# 17.10 comes with Firefox. How to install Chromium browser and sync bookmarks & extensions

Tags: software-installation, chromium

**Ubuntu 17.10 comes with Firefox as the default browser.**

Attempting to

```
sudo apt-get install chromium
```

informs that it is not found in the repository.

Question:  **How do I install Chromium (so I can use my Google login to synchronize bookmarks and extensions)?**

Comment: *All* versions of Ubuntu come with Firefox as default. I don't think any version has ever had Chromium as default, or even installed by default.

Comment: I don't understand that the first question has to do with the second question. Please don't tack hardly related questions together as that's going to make both of them harder to answer. Please open separate questions for (1) how to use profile synchronisation in Chromium and (2) how to deal with copy & paste issues.

Comment: If you mean, want to sync between linux and windows (or other device supported) using chrome based browser with 1 account you may use chrome browser instead. you can install chrome from official site. https://www.google.com/chrome but if want still using chromium, you can download from https://download-chromium.appspot.com/ 

Please make sure, you are on 64bit architecture of linux operating system or i686 before installing google chrome. because 32bit is end-of-support.

Comment: TNX.  That is exactly what I meant.  I now have it working in Ubuntu 16.04 - Chromium 62, I think.  It didn't work before, but this latest version seems fine.  The 'droids handle bookmarks differently but I think there will be a way to tackle that, too.  I have pretty much gone full-in with Google, with the exception of Docs - I store that stuff locally so I don't lose control of it like this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=google+blocking+docs

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Chromium can be installed by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

---

Note that Copy/Paste does not work the same with 17.10:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/971402/why-cant-i-copy-text-from-terminal-after-17-10-upgrade

Comment: maybe consider accepting this as the answer.  even though the command is missing the install argument and with the copy/paste mess, at least it's the right package name.

Answer (score -2):

**Chromium can be installed via `Ubuntu Software`**

Either click on the icon on the left or click on `Activities` in the menu bar, then search for it by name.

Click on the `Install` button.

Once it is installed, click on the `Launch` button to start it.

It is also available by clicking on the lower-left `Show Applications` icon and run Chromium from the screenful of icons that comes up.

From there on, it is the same as Ubuntu from 14.04 on.  i.e., while it is running you can right-click on the icon on the left as it runs in order to `Add to Favorites` so it stays there.

Sign In normally and verify your 2FA with the Google Authenticator or whichever method you use.

The first thing to do is visit Settings and verify your Sync settings.

In this first test case, the bookmarks were showing before completion of the Settings review.  (Most defaults were fine except towards the end where it still defaults to continuing to run background tasks even after exiting Chromium)

Extensions came later.

**Voila, Chromium is now installed just like on previous versions.**

---

Note:  Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 is not a LTS (Long Term Service) version.  LTS means that support is expected to last for five years.  17.10 promises 9 months of support.  In other words, it is not yet recommended for production environments.

Plus, people are still finding basic user interface bugs in it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/971402/why-cant-i-copy-text-from-terminal-after-17-10-upgrade?

---

The latest LTS version is Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.3, which can be downloaded here:

[Ubuntu Desktop Downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: 17.10 promises *90 days* of support -> 17.10 promises *9 months* of support